# Подсчет количества элементов jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Мне нужны высшие силы, поэтому я обращаюсь к вам.

Каким образом нужно построить цикл for что бы при уменьшении элементов через конструкцию if передавался элементу true ?
Я пробывал это сделать таким образом

```
if($("#findID").length<3) {
   // exists
}
```

Но появлялась проблема с тем что оно не обрабатывается в цикле.
Но мне кажется загвоздка в for.

**В примере все расписано, пример - http://jsfiddle.net/ad8zr/47/**

Comment: id должен быть уникальным!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

используйте селектор :visible:

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
$('.bloks').click(function() {
    $(this).hide()
    //console.log(
    $('.bloks:visible').length<3 && $('.class').addClass('произвольный_класс')
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/ad8zr/50/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ad8zr/51/
методы .length и .adClass

Comment: не в том у него проблема, я уже сделал же :)